# VMWare Fusion 3 on Mac Delete Snap Shot

Tags: vmware, snapshot, delete-file, vmware-fusion

I turned on AutoProtect and then decided I didn't want it. I found a several Gig size file in my VM folder.

I tried to delete it after Shutting Down the VM (Win 7)

But when I restarted Win 7 it complained that the snapshot files were needed. I restored them and was ok.

How do I get rid of these AutoProtect created snapshot files?

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Comment: Found Solution. Right click VM in the Library, Choose Snap Shots, find the snap shot and right click and choose delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found Solution. Right click VM in the Library, Choose Snap Shots, find the snap shot and right click and choose delete